# Sinatra loses parts of query string with curl

Tags: ruby, http, curl, sinatra

I have a strange problem with Sinatra:

```
class Server < Sinatra::Base
  before do
    puts params.inspect
  end
  get '/' do
  end
end
```

when I curl the url with:

```
chienandalusialocal:~ ngw$ curl http://0.0.0.0:9292/thing?a=100&b=200
```

the params hash contains only the first parameter:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Feb/2014 17:47:39] "GET /thing?a=100 HTTP/1.1" 401 - 0.0011
a=100
{"a"=>"100"}
```

What is happening here, and what should I do to fix the problem?

Comment: Perhaps your shell is interpreting the query string?

Comment: `curl 'http://0.0.0.0:9292/thing?a=100&b=200'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `&` in a bash shell will start the process and run it in background.

So if you run the command normally,

```
curl http://0.0.0.0:9292/thing?a=100&b=200
```

Bash interprets this as `curl http://0.0.0.0:9292/thing?a=100&` and delegates the process as a background process.

If you scroll up a little, you may find something like

```
[1] 14039
```

to signify the `pid` of the background process, and another statement at the end, like

```
[1]+  Done                    curl http://0.0.0.0:9292/thing?a=100
```

to signify completion of curl command.

---

The way out, as already suggested, is to either escape the ampersand, or put the string in quotes as follows:

```
curl http://0.0.0.0:9292/thing?a=100\&b=200
curl 'http://0.0.0.0:9292/thing?a=100&b=200'
```

Comment: And now I want to kill myself... Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Bash sees the ampersand and tries to do something with it.  You can either escape the ampersand, or put the string in quotes as bliof suggested.

```
curl http://0.0.0.0:9292/thing?a=100\&b=200

curl 'http://0.0.0.0:9292/thing?a=100&b=200'
```